# Observable wrapper for AsyncProducerConsumerQueue

Tags: c#, system.reactive, nito.asyncex

So I created an observable wrapper for Stephen Cleary's `AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<T>` with the following code.

I'm wondering if anyone here knows how I could have done this in a much simpler way?

- Could it have been written without a wrapper class?
- Would it be possible to prevent errors from multiple wrappers being applied to one queue?
- Could I make it connect on the first subscription instead of via a direct call to `Connect`? If so, what are the implications of that?
- Finally, how would you have done it?

```cs
using Nito.AsyncEx;
using System.Reactive;

static async Task ExampleUsage() {
    var queue = new AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<int>();
    var observable = queue.AsConnectableObservable();
    await queue.EnqueueAsync(1);
    observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
    observable.Connect();
    await queue.EnqueueAsync(2);
}

public static class AsyncExExtensions {
    public static IConnectableObservable<T> AsConnectableObservable<T>(this AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<T> queue) {
        return new ConnectableObservableForAsyncProducerConsumerQueue<T>(queue);
    }
}

class ConnectableObservableForAsyncProducerConsumerQueue<T> : IConnectableObservable<T> {

    readonly AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<T> Queue;

    long _isConnected = 0;
    ImmutableList<IObserver<T>> Observers = ImmutableList<IObserver<T>>.Empty;

    public ConnectableObservableForAsyncProducerConsumerQueue(AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<T> queue) {
        Queue = queue;
    }

    public IDisposable Connect() {
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _isConnected, 1) == 1) throw new InvalidOperationException("Observable cannot be connected more than once.");
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cts.Token;
        Task.Run(async () => {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    var @event = await Queue.DequeueAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    foreach (var observer in Observers)
                        observer.OnNext(@event);
                }
            } catch (Exception x) when (x is OperationCanceledException || x is InvalidOperationException) {
                foreach (var observer in Observers)
                    observer.OnCompleted();
            }
        });
        return Disposable.Create(() => {
            cts.Cancel();
            cts.Dispose();
        });
    }

    readonly object subscriberListMutex = new object();
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer) {
        lock (subscriberListMutex) {
            Observers = Observers.Add(observer);
        }
        return Disposable.Create(() => {
            lock (subscriberListMutex) {
                Observers = Observers.Remove(observer);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I am not an expert, so there may be aspects of this answer that I've overlooked - use with caution!

Consider the following two demos. These behave differently for the case where you have more than one observer. In the first demo, observers will compete for items on the queue, and in the second they will each receive a copy.

## Demo #1 - Cold observable

```cs
var queue = new AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<int>();

// This is a cold observable, so each observer is fed by its own individual dequeue loop
// and therefore will be 'competing' with other observers for queued items.
var coldObservable = Observable
    // Create an observable that asynchronously waits for items to become available on the
    // queue and then emits them to the observer. This will be cancelled when the observer
    // is unsubscribed. 
    .Create<int>(async (observer, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var item = await queue.DequeueAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine($"Dequeued {item}");
            observer.OnNext(item);
        }
    })
    // If an InvalidOperationException is thrown by the above, continue with
    // an empty observable instead of the error. This effectively catches an
    // `OnError(InvalidOperationException)` and turns it into an `OnCompleted()`.
    .Catch<int, InvalidOperationException>(exn =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught InvalidOperation");
        return Observable.Empty<int>();
    });

Console.WriteLine("TEST COLD");

await queue.EnqueueAsync(1);
Console.WriteLine("Enqueued 1");

Console.WriteLine("Subscribing A");
coldObservable.Subscribe(
    item => Console.WriteLine($"A received {item}"),
    () => Console.WriteLine("A completed"));

Console.WriteLine("Subscribing B");
coldObservable.Subscribe(
    item => Console.WriteLine($"B received {item}"),
    () => Console.WriteLine("B completed"));

await queue.EnqueueAsync(2);
Console.WriteLine("Enqueued 2");

await queue.EnqueueAsync(3);
Console.WriteLine("Enqueued 3");

queue.CompleteAdding();
Console.WriteLine("Completed adding");

Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
await Task.Delay(2000);

Console.WriteLine("DONE");

// TEST COLD
// Enqueued 1
// Subscribing A
// Dequeued 1
// A received 1
// Subscribing B
// Enqueued 2
// Enqueued 3
// Completed adding
// Waiting...
// Dequeued 2
// Dequeued 3
// A received 2
// B received 3
// Caught InvalidOperation
// Caught InvalidOperation
// A completed
// B completed
// DONE
```

## Demo #2 - Hot observable

```cs
var queue = new AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<int>();

var coldObservable = // defined same as above

// This is a hot observable, so each observer receives the same items from the queue.
var hotObservable = coldObservable
    // Publish the cold observable to create an `IConnectableObservable` that will subscribe
    // to the dequeue loop when connected and emit the same items to all observers.
    .Publish()
    // Automatically connect to the published observable when the first observer subscribes
    // and automatically disconnect when the last observer unsubscribes. This means that the
    // first observer will receive any items queued before it subscribes, but additional
    // observers will only receive items queued after they subscribed.
    .RefCount();

Console.WriteLine("TEST HOT");

await queue.EnqueueAsync(1);
Console.WriteLine("Enqueued 1");

Console.WriteLine("Subscribing A");
hotObservable.Subscribe(
    item => Console.WriteLine($"A received {item}"),
    () => Console.WriteLine("A completed"));

Console.WriteLine("Subscribing B");
hotObservable.Subscribe(
    item => Console.WriteLine($"B received {item}"),
    () => Console.WriteLine("B completed"));

await queue.EnqueueAsync(2);
Console.WriteLine("Enqueued 2");

await queue.EnqueueAsync(3);
Console.WriteLine("Enqueued 3");

queue.CompleteAdding();
Console.WriteLine("Completed adding");

Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
await Task.Delay(2000);

Console.WriteLine("DONE");

// TEST HOT
// Enqueued 1
// Subscribing A
// Dequeued 1
// A received 1
// Subscribing B
// Enqueued 2
// Enqueued 3
// Dequeued 2
// Completed adding
// Waiting...
// A received 2
// B received 2
// Dequeued 3
// A received 3
// B received 3
// Caught InvalidOperation
// A completed
// B completed
// DONE
```

To answer your original questions:

> Could it have been written without a wrapper class?

Yes, see demos above.

> Would it be possible to prevent errors from multiple wrappers being applied to one queue?

The approaches demo-ed above do not prevent other parties from dequeueing items (or performing any other operation on the queue). If you want ensure you only expose a single `IObservable<T>` for a given queue, consider encapsulating the queue itself, by creating an `ObservableProducerConsumerQueue<T>` that internally creates and manages its own `AsyncProducerConsumerQueue`. You can expose an `EnqueueAsync` method that just delegates to the internal queue and use one of the demo-ed observables above to either expose the observable as a property or implement the `IObservable<T>` interface.

> Could I make it connect on the first subscription instead of via a direct call to Connect? If so, what are the implications of that?

Demo #2 shows this behaviour and describes the implications. If you want to be able to subscribe observers before connecting, skip the `RefCount` call and use the `IConnectableObservable` returned by `Publish` as before.

> Finally, how would you have done it?

As described above, I would have encapsulated the queue and exposed an `IObservable` or `IConnectableObservable` using one of the approaches demo-ed above.